# Panel Bar deleted in Linux Mint Gloria

Tags: linux-mint

I'm new with linux and by accident I deleted my panel, because it was kinda messed up, and I thought if I deleted it, I would get later another option to put it back, well no! And now I have no access to anything more than I had as a shortcut on my desktop which is dolphin firefox, and the trash. Is there any way to restore the bar without reinstalling the whole OS? I'm sure there's gotta be...Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're using KDE by the Dolphin reference, so you can:

- Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> to open the **Run Application** dialog
- Enter `dcop kicker kicker restart` and run it

If you're referring to gnome-panel however, you can restore it like so:

- Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> to open the **Run Application** dialog
- Select the terminal from the list and run it
- In terminal enter these 3 commands (each followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd>)

```
gconftool-2 --shutdown
rm -rf ~/.gconf/apps/panel
pkill gnome-panel
```

Comment: Thank you guys! for you prompt answer! but it's still not working! And in the case that I had to reboot, how could I do that? coz...I got no 'start' bar, if I may...

Comment: Press Alt+f2 and open terminal then type reboot.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this, it works for ubuntu, should be the same for any gnome install. Press alt+F2 to open the run bar and the type in terminal to open gnome-terminal. You can then type in each of these commands.

```
gconftool-2 --shutdown
rm -rf ~/.gconf/apps/panel
pkill gnome-panel
```

Comment: Thank you guys! for you prompt answer! but it's still not working! And in the case that I had to reboot, how could I do that? coz...I got no 'start' bar, if I may...

Comment: You can reboot buy typing the following in the terminal

    shutdown -r now

You could try just running 
    
    gnome-panel &

Which should start up a panel, I don't run gnome anymore, but I believe you could also try running gnome-control-center or gnome-system-settings and see if you can get to a panel configuration screen from there

Comment: Thank you! But I'm afraid something's missing. I'm runnign KDE, it says in the booting menu. When I try 'gnome-panel &' it's like it's not even accepting the command, coz... it's just stays the same (the terminal I mean) it won't even go away like with the other commands you said in you first comment. Any idea why?

Comment: hey! when I tried to add a widget form the gnome symbol on the upper right corner and wanted to add the kget panel applet, I got an error saying 'could not find requested component: kgetpanelbar' so that probably has something to do with not being able to restore the panel bar! Don't you think?

Comment: I apologize - I missed that you are running KDE. If you right click the desktop, do you get an option menu to appear? In my menu I have the option to Add Panel ?